# install numpy and matplotlib of python2.7 numpy on window7 64 system

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I installed python 2.7 in the window 7 64-bit system, it works.However, when I install the numpy and matplotlib , the setup can not find the path,
the version of matplotlib is 'matplotlib-1.4.2.win-amd64-py2.7.exe'
it showed the error'Python version 2.7 required, which was not found in the regestry'.

I have already add the python path to the 'path'in windows,

I don't understand why it like this.

Thank you very much if you could give me some clue about this.

Bests,
LI LI

Comment: find your package in http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alles,

I think I did resolved the problems!

The most tricky issue is

when installing some Python Windows modules lies in: you have 64-bit Python, but a 32-bit installer of new modules.

64-bit Python installer write to: HKLM|HKCU\SOFTWARE\

while 32-bit installer looks at : HKLM|HKCU\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\

Therefore, if I install all the numpy, matplotlib and so on in 32-bit version, this problem can not show any more.

And for downloading all the bianries, the link here is very powerful,

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

or install the winpython directly could ignore all the problems as well.

Good luck for others when meet the similiar problem^^

Thank you for all your replies as well.

Bests,
Lili